# Pandas Profiling-Interpret .html data to a readable table format using python, pyspark

Tags: pandas, pyspark, pandas-profiling

I've used pandas profiling to display the pandas dataframe data in .html via the Databricks, is there a way I can make use of this great .html report in table format. From further automation point of view, I would need to transform the .html report into a table format. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Even tried to parse using pd.read_html() but no luck.

```
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
profile = ProfileReport(data, title="Pandas Profiling Report", explorative=True, minimal=True)
p = profile.to_html()
displayHTML(p)
```

[image]